# Can I use the Facebook JavaScript SDK in an offline web app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

My Web based offline app which will run using phonegap (html, css, jquery)

The app doesn't have an actual web address.

Is it still possible to use the Facebook JavaScript API?

Answer (score 1):

Using the Facebook JavaScript API requires an active internet connection so it is not possible to use it offline.

If by "offline" you mean that your app is not hosted from a web server but locally inside the app "web app" container, then the answer is yes, you can use the Facebook JS API in this setup using phonegap (Cordova).